# Umbraco Surface Controller Not Routing Correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, umbraco7, umbraco6

I have a bit of trouble getting a surface controller to fire correctly.

```
public class SocialShareSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("hello world");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get to the controller via this URL: http://website.local/umbraco/surface/SocialShare/Index/

But I am getting 404 error..... If I then move this file to the App_Code folder go to the same URL I get this error

A route named 'umbraco-surface-SocialShareSurface' is already in the route collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

Any Ideas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you name your Surface Controller like you have above (including "Surface" in the name) then your route would need to also include Surface in the Controller name:

```
http://website.local/umbraco/surface/SocialShareSurface/Index/
```

You can just call your Surface Controller class `SocialShareController` - you don't need the Surface keyword in the class name at all.

Comment: 4 eyes are better than 2 - Yes I noticed this a few hours later all working now.

Comment: Glad you got it working - the documentation isn't exactly clear on that point :)